# Used the text-decoration syntax in css, but it keeps showing the Unknown property 'text-decoration-style' error

Tags: html, css, underline

I am a beginner in web dev/html/css (4hrs old). I have hit a wall in CSS, while the code works it shows error msg in the CSSLint report

I am working with the text-decoration syntax, the code is -

```css
p {
  color: #417D7A;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.underline {
  text-decoration: #525E75 underline;
  text-decoration-style: double;
  text-underline-position: under;
}
```

```html
<P class=underline> Text for underlining </P>
<P> Other text <P>
```

If i remove the text-decoration-style: double;/ text-underline-position: under; the error msg goes away. Can someone tell me why this is happening. I use Atom as my editor.

Also, attaching a snip of the code to show what exactly it is.

P.S. Im sorry if this is a duplicate question, if you can help me with the right link it would be great and i will take this query off. I tried looking for an answer but i couldn't find it.

[image]

Comment: Don't worry too much about CSS Lint. If it works, then you are fine.

Comment: What browser are you on? Safari for example doesn’t understand some of the text decoration stuff so your checker may be telling the truth, it’s often a good idea to look at caniuse.com to see what bits of CSS are OK more or less anywhere and which aren’t.

Comment: @A Haworth Thanks for the input - im using chrome for the dev work, but i do use safari (not sure if its relevant). I will check out caniuse, thanks alot.